# NSTextAlignmentCenter still not working

Tags: ios, uitableview

Through [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12932580/ios6-uilabel-not-center-text-aligned) I've learned that in order to center align text in UILabel via **NSTextAlignmentCenter** I must disable "letter tighten spacing" and [this guy agrees](http://questiontrack.com/table-view-cell39s-label-won39t-center-align-unless-number-of-lines-is-1-988008.html).

They mention disabling this option in interface builder, however, my uilabel isn't accessible in IB as far as I know. This is because I am trying to change the "textLabel" of a cell in a uitableview. I proceeded to attempt to try disabling things in code:

```
cell.textLabel.numberOfLines = 1;
cell.textLabel.adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth      = NO;
cell.textLabel.adjustsLetterSpacingToFitWidth = NO;
cell.textLabel.textAlignment = NSTextAlignmentCenter;
cell.textLabel.text = @"My Centered Text";
```

However, none of these seem to have any effect. The text is still left aligned.

Comment: cell.textLabel.textAlignment = NSTextAlignmentCenter; should be all you need. The first 3 lines are all the default values, so no need to set them.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Found the problem! Had to [change the cell style](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3467288/center-align-text-in-uitableviewcell-problem) to UITableViewCellStyleDefault:

```
cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:simpleTableIdentifier];
```

Comment: Duh !  I had the same issue, as I was doing the same thing !  Thanks for sharing.